# Excluindo registros de uma tabela muito grande

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Temos uma tabela no SQLServer com mais de 154 milhões de registros e precisamos
apagar todos os registros cujo DTANO seja menor do que 2017.

Porém o banco é acessado via WEB e, claro, não pode ficar travado.

Tentando resolver a questão escrevi o seguinte script:

```
WHILE ( 0 = 0 )
 BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT TOP (1) * FROM TBL712 WHERE DTANO < 2017  )
     BREAK

    IF ( DATEPART( HOUR, GETDATE()) = 6 ) 
    BEGIN
      IF (( DATEPART( weekday, GETDATE()) > 1 ) AND ( DATEPART( weekday, GETDATE()) < 7 ))
      BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '13:00:00'
      END
    END

   ;WITH CTE AS ( SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM TBL712 WHERE DTANO < 2017 )
     DELETE CTE

 END
```

As 06:00 h o script executa o WAITFOR por 13 horas. Portanto, volta a rodar apenas as 19:00 da noite, mas mesmo assim, o acesso ao sistema fica muito lento quando o script esta rodando.

Achei que nesse momento, com o script suspenso a interferência seria minima, para não dizer nenhuma.

Quando o script é cancelado e emite todas aquelas mensagens:

> (1000 row(s) affected)
>
> (1000 row(s) affected)
>
> (1000 row(s) affected)
>
> (1000 row(s) affected)

Ele volta a funcionar de maneira razoável.

Tem como eu emitir essas mensagens enquanto o script ainda roda?

O que eu poderia melhorar, ou como fazer isso diferente?

Comment: se usar `SET NOCOUNT ON` não aparecem essas mensagens e poupa no tráfego de rede.

Comment: Já pensou em mudar a estratégia? Copie todos os registros que devem permanecer para uma tabela auxiliar e após a cópia concluída dê um DROP na antiga tabela e um RENAME na tabela auxiliar. Creio que o downtime será bem menor.